# Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable

Tags: activemq-classic, jetty-9, tomcat9

I am trying to upgrade ActiveMQ jar to its latest version. It requires me to upgrade Jetty to 9.4 version.
I have current setup as Tomcat 9 + ActiveMQ 5.12 + jetty-all-8.1.
I want to upgrade it as Tomcat 9 + ActiveMQ 5.15 + jetty-all-9.4.

After doing the changes when I try to start my application it gives me below error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5125)
```

It looks like Jetty 9.4 has JSR-356 implementation and it is conflicting with Tomcat.

Comment: Do you actually need JSR-356 functionality?

Comment: No I do not need this specifically.

Comment: @Naveen Did you find any solution for this ?